# pecl.php.net down?

Tags: php

I am trying to install mongo extension on my ubuntu but pecl.php.net seems down.

```
sudo pecl install mongo
```

doesn't work, is it just me or pecl server are down for you too ? 
I get

```
No releases available for package "pecl.php.net/mongo"
install failed
```

maybe somebody can try it at home.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I know you already accepted my answer, glad to help, but I had started thinking and I knew I had an alternative that was better. I dug that out and added it to my reply (posted so that you're aware of it). It might be worth adding the site to your bookmarks. I've found it handy in the past.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not just you, it is down for me and it is down from the hotel's wireless, and it is down from my phone. Additionally, it appears to be down for everyone else.

You can check [this site](http://downforeveryoneorjustme.com/http://pecl.php.net/) to see if it is still down. You can then use that site in the future. A search engine finds lots of such sites.

---

**EDIT:** I knew I'd seen a better site but was unable to find it in my bookmarks. I scoured around and managed to login to a computer at home, well sort of, and was able to find the bookmarks folder. I was pretty sure that I knew where it was but not what it was called.

[TADA](https://www.uptrends.com/tools/uptime)

There you go. That is a MUCH better tool than the above linked site. The linked site checks from some 39 disparate sites from around the globe. There are other sites just like it but I've used this one in the past and had good luck with it, which is how it ended up in my bookmarks. I am not affiliated - just a user.